# Regex - At least 1 number, 1 letter, 1 special character and at least 3 characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I wanna test my own regex in order to understand how can i use it and create my custom regex.

I tried this one :

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[\W_]){3}$
```

`(?=.*\d)` => at least 1 number.
`(?=.*[a-zA-Z])` => at least 1 letter.
`(?=.*[\W_])`=> at least 1 special character.
`{3}` => at least 3 characters.

Unfortunately, it doesn't work, but i want at least 1 number, 1 letter and 1 special character, and at least 3 characters in my input. When the user types those 3 types of characters, my message disappears because the regex is correct ^^

Sorry for my bad english, I can give you more details if you want and thank you for the help :)

Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your `{3}` quantifier applies to your last look-ahead, which is nonsensical : it means that at the start of the text, you must match 3 times the look-ahead, which is a given if it matches once since lookaround are 0-width matches.

You could use the following :

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[\W_]).{3,}$
```

which specifies, aside from your existing look-aheads, that at least 3 characters must be matched.

If you just test the string, it would also be enough to match

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[\W_]).{3}
```

without an end anchor : you match 3 characters, and stop matching what follows since your requisites are met.

Answer (score 4):

If you want 1 digit, 1 alpha, 1 special character, those are already *at least 3 characters*.

```
^(?=\D*\d)(?=.*?[a-zA-Z]).*[\W_].*$
```

[Here's a demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/bY1cM1/1). Or for only matching:

```
^(?=\D*\d)(?=.*?[a-zA-Z]).*[\W_]
```

- `(?=\D*\d)` The first lookahead requires one digit (preceded by any `\D` *non-digits*).
- `(?=.*?[a-zA-Z])` second lookahead requires one alpha (preceded by any characters).
- `.*[\W_]` matching until one special character.

All together requires at least 3 different characters: 1 digit, 1 alpha, 1 special.

Comment: Interesting way to do it, and more efficient than my answer, but I'd rather have a novice developer try to maintain my answer than yours :) It would be great if you could explain in your answer how matching the look-aheads guarantees a certain number of characters !

Comment: @Aaron added a bit more of explanation.